# Blank app icon in iOS app

Tags: xcode, icons

When I run my app from XCode on a device or in the simulator, the app icon is blank.  I am using the image asset mechanism and have all icons filled.  When I went back to using the old approach and filled out my .info file with icons, same thing.  What's going on?  I am using XCode 6.1 and building for iOS 7.

Also, the target under TARGETS on the project page, has the proper icon.

Here is a screenshot showing the icon that appears in the simulator and device:

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing the referenced assets under General:

[image: Screenshot showing referencing assets]

Here is a screenshot showing contents of Images.xcassets:

[image]

Comment: It isn't enough to _have_ icons; you have to _tell_ the system where they are. Can you post a screen shot proving that you are specifying the icon source correctly in the target's General pane?

Comment: @matt see screenshots above now.

Comment: Hmm. Could the problem be that you are "building for iOS 7"? What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @matt that's the deployment target

Comment: This is going to sound nutty, but could you just try making a new project and setting it up with your icons just as you've done in this one? I'm wondering if there's some kind of corruption. It would be useful to convince yourself that icons actually do work. :)

Comment: It's the deployment target but does the problem arise on both iOS 8 and iOS 7 simulator, or just on iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: @matt ok, i created a test project, and used my png icon files to create a new app icon asset catalog, with deployment target of 7, and that works.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this project was originally created a year ago, but I have used it for a few weeks in XCode 6.1 already.

Comment: Well, you've solved it now. The icons work in the new project, so migrate your code files into it (and the other image files and so forth) and you're all set. I wouldn't spend any time worrying about why the old one doesn't work, though I suspect you're correct that it has to do with the upgrade path.

Comment: It's a very big project, I am not interested in moving all those assets.  I need to fix the current project.

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the assets folder from the project and then created a new asset catalog.  Closed project.  Moved old json and png files to under new asset catalog folders.  Reopened XCode.  Works.

Currently I can't browse files under the Images.xcassets folder in the project navigator, whereas before I could.  Perhaps this can be an indicator to you if you encounter similar problems.